# Impossible for me to install aptitude and to add trusty repos

Tags: 14.04, apt, add-apt-repository

Trying to run `sudo apt-get install aptitude`:

```
Package aptitude is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to add the trusty repositories to my sources files... But I believe there is something wrong with my sources file for apt. Could I get some help as to why `sudo apt-get update` fails with::

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am currently running:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Here's my source file:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse 
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Googling about this has been unsuccessful since many options of repositories being added to the sources file also cause the same problem.

Comment: We need a current sources list directly from your computer. That sources list points to 12.04 repos. Also your error message talks about a repo that isn't even in your sources list. May want to post contents of files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d as well. Can't help without proper information. The 404 not found means that source target doesn't exist.

Comment: The listed source file is from my computer. I do see it includes weird lines referring to another distribution. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by Tadaen Sylvermane, I realized there was something sort of corrupted on the originally-listed sources file. I decided to replace that with a default sources file for my distribution. I went to: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php, selected the default repositories for my country and distribution, generated a fresh sources file, replaced my old file with the newly generated file, and executed an apt update.

As shown, some URLs were still missing:

```
ejspeiro@Eduardo-Alienware-14:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Ign file:  InRelease
Get:1 file:  Release.gpg [819 B]
Get:2 file:  Release [574 B]                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease [65.9 kB]         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [588 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse armhf Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 785 kB in 5min 41s (2,302 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However, when executed the installation of aptitude, it all went great. Furthermore, the update system starting prompting me for some updates now.

As far as to why https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php generates source files with outdated URLs baffles me. Furthermore, I do not understand why, if this is an LTS which is supposed to be supported until 2019, then why are repositories that could not be found?

Anyway, I am satisfied with this procedure and its outcome, which is why I decided to post it as an answer to my original question.

Comment: The official Ubuntu mirror for the US doesn't provide binary packages for the `armf` architecture, only `amd64` and `i386`. That's why you got those warning messages. Repogen doesn't do anything architecture-specific because `sources.list` doesn't normally contain anything like that. It's also strange that you configured DPKG to use all three aforementioned architectures. Afaik only some virtualized platforms can support all these instruction sets.